# How do I open .cpp file from the github directory?

Tags: command-line, g++

I'm a total newbie here. How do I open .cpp file from the github directory? what command should I use? I'm in the directory where the .cpp file is stored but I do not know how to open that in the terminal.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can open the file in any text editor. Try:

```
nano file_name.cpp
```